# How to write test so that the controller can connect to API?

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, mocking

I'm trying to deal with Rest api tests.
Well, the controller in my code connects to the external api parsing and returns in the form of JSON.
I'm trying to run a test so that it returns the result of my application’s logic.
Unfortunately, during testing I can't connect with api github.

> ```
> java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
> Expected :200
> Actual   :404
> ```

```
  @WebMvcTest(RepositoryDetailsController.class)
  @ContextConfiguration(classes = RepositoryDetailsController.class)

 class RepositoryDetailsControllerTestt {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;


    @MockBean
    private RepositoryDetailsService service;
    @InjectMocks
    private RepositoryDetailsController repositoryDetailsController;


   @Before
    public void setUp() {

        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(repositoryDetailsController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void mockTest() throws Exception {

        RepositoryDetailsResponse details = new RepositoryDetailsResponse();
        details.setDescription("Ruby toolkit for the GitHub API");
        details.set"https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb.git");
        details.setStars("57892");
        details.setName("octokit/octokit.rb");

        mvc.perform(get("repository/{owner}/{repository}","octokit","octokit.rb")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", hasSize(5)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.fullName").value(details.getName()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.description").value(details.getDescription()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.cloneUrl").value(details.getUrl()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.stars").value(details.getStars()));
    }
```

Comment: can you try with `mvc.perform(get("/repository/{owner}/{repository}","octokit","octokit.rb")`? Also, would be nice to have the output of `.andDo(print())`

Comment: Ideally you would not be connecting to an actual resource during the test--doing that means your test data is at the mercy of the server, which means you can't actually *test* since you aren't controlling the response. It also means if there's any issues between the test machine and the server you'll have nondeterministic tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid it you usually don't want to connect to an external API in your tests. Having an external API test dependency makes life harder e.g. what if the API is down or what if the API had a breaking change?

There are few tools that you can use to mock this external API, hardcoding the expected responses while still making the request:

- [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) - very generic, exposes a mock server that can be used with any library that makes the API call
- Spring's [`MockRestServiceServer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html) - especially useful if your code is using `RestTemplate` to make the API call
- [Test Containers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) - if you have a Docker image that provides a mock API

In your example it looks like you attempted to use `MockMvc` instead of `MockRestServiceServer` but there is not enough code to tell what you are doing exactly.